# Push form name into POST data sent by Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, jquery

I'm collecting all data from form input fields with `serialize()` function. But it doesn't include submit button value even if I pressed submit button. How to push form name into POST data (IN my case i wanna push form name into `formData` variable)?

The code looks like that

```
$("#signup_form").submit(function () {
         var form = $(this),
            formData = form.serialize(),
            formUrl = form.attr('action'),
            formMethod = form.attr('method');
....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Append it to the query string generated by `serialize` I guess.  I'm not quite sure what you're doing with the form data in the rest of your function, full code may help, but the snippet below is probably sufficient.

```
$("#signup_form").submit(function () {
         var form = $(this),
            formData = form.serialize() + '&formName=' + form.attr('name'),
            formUrl = form.attr('action'),
            formMethod = form.attr('method'),
....
```